# Prove that the equation $x^{3}-3x+b=0$ has at most one root in the interval $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to prove that the equation  $x^{3}-3x+b=0$  has at most one  root in the interval $[-1,1]$.

My attempt:

We consider the function $g(x)=x^{3}-3x+b$.Now since it is a polynomial it is differenciable and given that $g(x)$ has odd degree it has a root.
We now take a look to the derivative of $g(x)$ that is $g'(x)=3x^{2}-3$ and we notice that the equation $3x^{2}-3=0$ has two solutions $x=+1,-1$.**Then we note that in the interval $[-1,1]$  $g′(x) \le 0$ so $g$ is decreasing, and, as this is a polynomial, it does not remain constant, on any interval and $g$ is hence is strickly decreasing. So g cannot have multiple zeros. Or we can state this as follows,  $g′(x)<0$ on the open interval then by the MVI we have that: (g(x)−g(y))/(x−y)=g′(c) with c∈(−1,1). As g′(c)<0 the ratio is <0 so $g$ is stricly monotonic**.

Then there exists at most 1 root at the interval  $[-1,1]$.
Can you tell me if I am clear and right? and How can I fix that errors please? thank you a lot. :)

Comment: Have you tried the intermediate value theorem? Try showing that for any $b$, there's only one crossing of the axis in that interval.

Comment: Try using Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: I have tried that but my function does not hold the hypothesis for every b :( thank you

Comment: More to the point you can determine the sign of the derivative in the interior of the interval.

Comment: The function is strictly decreasing on the closed interval $[-1,1]$ Had to think about the endpoints for a minute...

Comment: For all b @WillJagy? , can you explain it please, Im sorry because of my ignorance  thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your point is not clear. The fact to note is that
$$
g'(x) = 3x^2 - 3
$$
does not take both positive and negative values on the interval $[-1,1]$. Hence $g$ is monotonic, and has at most one zero.

Comment: Thank you but how is this possible "does not take positive and negative values on the interval"?

Comment: it can become zero but remains $\le 0$. You never get $g'(x)>0$.

Comment: I still I litle bit confused? I'm sorry :)

Comment: You always have $g'(x) \ge 0$ so $g$ is decreasing. As this is a polynomial, it does not remain constant on any interval and $g$ is hence strictly decreasing. So $g$ cannot have multiple zeros.

Comment: or, a simplier proof: $g'<0$ on the open interval $(-1,1)$ implies $g$ strictly monotonic.

Comment: Thank you @mookid but can I say like that ? or I have to prove or do more math to proof what I want because of the formality in the way I write my proof thank you :)

Comment: this is a consequence of the mean value theorem, actually! $(g(x)-g(y)) / (x-y) = g'(c)$ with $c\in (-1,1)$. As $g'(c)<0$ the ratio is $<0$.

Comment: Good thank you @mookid, then the conclusion is that I can say like that isn't?

Comment: yes, you can!${}$

Comment: Thank you @mookid then with this we are done, and I liked your prove because it was very easy to follow

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^3-3x+b$

Let's suppose $-1\leq x \lt y \leq 1$

Then $f(y)-f(x)=y^3-3y+b-(x^3-3x+b)=(y-x)(x^2+xy+y^2-3)$

The first factor $y-x$ is positive. We have $x^2\leq 1, xy \lt 1, y^2 \leq 1$ so that $x^2+xy+y^2-3$ is negative.

This means that $f(y)\lt f(x)$

Suppose $-1\leq y, z\leq 1$ and $f(z) =0$. If $y\lt z$ then $f(y)\gt f(z)=0$ and if $y\gt z$ then $f(y)\lt f(z)=0$

So if there is one root in the interval, there can't be another.

Much better to draw a diagram, and get a sense of what is going on.

Much better to develop an understanding of the shapes of functions.

Easier to use the derivative and to note that a negative derivative means a decreasing function.

Comment: Thank you a lot @MarkBennet but with this you only prove that if there is one root in the interval, there can't be another, but it doesn't prove that there exists one isn't ?

Comment: @user162343 Depending on $b$ there need not be a root, but you asked for proof that there is at most one. At most one includes none.

Comment: Ok :) I understand but then with the above proof we are done with the problem isn't?